# Celery multiple instances and Redis

Tags: redis, celery

I have two servers running Celery and one Redis database. They both listen to the same queue as they are meant to divide the "workload". Tasks are queued onto Redis, but it looks like both my Celery servers pick up the task at the same time, hence executing it twice (once on each server.) Is there a way to prevent this with the Redis/Celery setup?

Thank you,

Comment: The reason I think the tasks are executed twice is because I see them in both Celery Flower "tasks" tab. But maybe this is due to monitoring events rather than actual execution of tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of my servers were using the same name for the celery workers. Since then I've added %h at the end of the worker name (-n my_worker_%h) to show the hostname. This way Celery Flower displays all of the workers in their own line, and there is no confusion more possible.

Comment: You didn't mention if the tasks stopped getting executed twice or not. I am facing the same issue and adding %h didn't help.

Comment: The tasks were not executed twice. They were just "reported" by Flower as being executed twice. Once I set a different name for each of them, the reporting of the task execution became correct (once per task)

Comment: Thanks but in my case its running twice. When I inspect `celery -A proj inspect active_queues` I see two servers showing their queues they are listening to and they are pointing to same default queue name `celery`. Still the task issued by django app gets executed twice by both servers. Thought you faced the same issue. Will open another question.